# Pythonic way of getting third word in a line if it exists?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a large text output which looks like this:

```
name = 
place = San Francisco
number = A901
name = Andy
place = Menlo Park
number = 8910
name = Beth
place = Oregon
number = 80FD
name = Andrew
place = MountainView
number = 8955
name = Cooper
place = San Jose
number = 8910
name = David
place = San Jose
number = A33B
name = Beth
place = Oregon
number = 80FD
name = Elizabeth
place = Portland
number = 09FC
name = 
place = Dallas
number = CC87
name = Anderson
place = Sunnyvale
number = 8755
```

I want to extract the names:

1. from the name field of a line, if it exists,
2. and if it is not equal to a word which begins with 'And'.
3. and is not equal to the current value in my_name.

I am currently doing this using:

```
# Example case: when my_name = Beth.
my_name = 'Beth'
for line in text_op.splitlines():
    if (re.search("name", line) and (len(line.split()) > 2)):
        name = line.split()[2]
        if (name != 'Beth' and not re.search("And", name)):
           print(name)
```

Is there a better and more pythonic way of doing this. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extracting names not starting with `and` use this regex:

```
name = ((?!and)\w+)
```

Then you can simply compare it with `my_name`.

```
my_name = 'Beth'
regex = re.compile(r'name = ((?!and)\w+)', re.IGNORECASE)
for line in text_op.splitlines():
    match = regex.match(line)
    if match:
        name = match.group(1)
        if name != my_name:
            print(name)
```